# Implementing Delegate Protocol

Tags: swift, delegates, cocoapods, protocols

I am attempting to implement a delegate protocol but I am apparently doing it all wrong.  I am using a cocoapod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SMDatePicker, which I have attempted to contact the developer for assistance but so far he's never responded to me.

After I added the pod and installed it, I added the .swift file to my project and added the following method which displays the date picker just fine:

```
class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, SMDatePickerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblDate: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialize
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CalculatorViewController.tapFunction))
    lblDate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    lblDate.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    // Set label date
    let dt = Date()
    lblDate.text = dt.asString(style: .short)
}

@IBAction func datePicker(picker: SMDatePicker, didPickDate date: NSDate) {
    let picked = date as Date
    lblDate.text = picked.asString(style: .short)
}

@IBAction func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var picker: SMDatePicker = SMDatePicker()
    picker.pickerMode  = .date
    picker.showPickerInView(view, animated: true)
    print("tap working")
}

func datePicker(_ picker: SMDatePicker, didPickDate date: Date) {
    let picked = date
    print(date)
}
```

}

I am trying to get the result from the date picker.  According to the pod the various methods are as follows:

```
 // Initialize
var picker: SMDatePicker = SMDatePicker()
// Set delegate
picker.delegate = self
You have SMDatePickerDelegate protocol to handle picker’s events. Here are list:
datePickerWillAppear(picker: SMDatePicker)
datePickerDidAppear(picker: SMDatePicker)
datePicker(picker: SMDatePicker, didPickDate date: NSDate)
datePickerDidCancel(picker: SMDatePicker)
datePickerWillDisappear(picker: SMDatePicker)
datePickerDidDisappear(picker: SMDatePicker)
```

My problem is I'm not sure how to implement this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `delegate` of your `SMDatePicker`. Also, you have two renditions of `didPickDate`. The correct syntax in Swift is `datePicker(_:didPickDate:)`, where the second parameter is a `Date`, not a `NSDate`.

Thus:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialize
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapLabel(_:)))
        dateLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        dateLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Set label date
        let now = Date()
        dateLabel.text = now.asString(style: .short)
    }

    @objc func didTapLabel(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let picker = SMDatePicker()
        picker.delegate = self                        // Don’t forget to set the delegate
        picker.pickerMode  = .date
        picker.showPickerInView(view, animated: true)
        print("tap working")
    }
}

extension ViewController: SMDatePickerDelegate {
    func datePicker(_ picker: SMDatePicker, didPickDate date: Date) {
        dateLabel.text = date.asString(style: .short)
    }
}
```

I personally would put the `SMDatePickerDelegate` methods in its own `extension`, just to keep the code nice and organized. Also, your tap gesture recognizer can just be declared as `@objc`, not `@IBAction` (as the latter suggests you’re hooking it up to an action in Interface Builder (hence the `IB`), whereas you’re just hooking it up via an Objective-C `#selector` pattern).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I think I understand the process better now.  i'm going to take your suggestions and use them in a few other programs as a way of enhancing what you taught me here.  Much appreciated.  Cup of Joe on me :)

Answer (score 0):

First, add an outlet to `CalculatorViewController` that references the date picker in your storyboard/XIB.

Then, in `viewDidLoad()`, assign your class as its delegate.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: SMDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   self.datePicker.delegate = self
}
```

The class that you add as its delegate must conform to the `SMDatePickerDelegate` protocol, which your example does.

Then, simply add the methods to your class to react to its events. For example:

```swift
func datePicker(picker: SMDatePicker, didPickDate date: NSDate) {
    debugPrint("date picked! \(date)")
}

func datePickerDidCancel(picker: SMDatePicker) {
    debugPrint("date picker cancelled")
}
```